# Python Pandas: Get index of multiple rows which column matches certain value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Given a `DataFrame` with the columns `xk` and `yk`, we want to find the indexes of the `DataFrame` in which the values for `xk` and `yk ==0`.

I have it  working perfectly fine for just the one column but I cant get it working for both

```
b = (df[df['xk'] ==0]).index.tolist()
```

How would I do it for `xk` and `yk` at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can check if all values are `True` in compared subset `['xk', 'yk']` by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
b = df[(df[['xk', 'yk']] == 0).all(1)].index.tolist()
```

Another solution is add second condition with `&`:

```
b = (df[(df['xk']  == 0) & (df['yk'] == 0)].index.tolist())
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'xk':[0,2,3],
                   'yk':[0,5,0],
                   'aa':[0,1,0]})

print (df)
   aa  xk  yk
0   0   0   0
1   1   2   5
2   0   3   0

b = df[(df[['xk', 'yk']] == 0).all(1)].index.tolist()
print (b)
[0]

b1 = (df[(df['xk']  == 0) & (df['yk'] == 0)].index.tolist())
print (b1)
[0]
```

Second solution is faster:

```
#length of df = 3k
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [294]: %timeit df[(df[['xk', 'yk']] == 0).all(1)].index.tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 ms per loop

In [295]: %timeit (df[(df['xk']  == 0) & (df['yk'] == 0)].index.tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 828 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, what about if i wanted to return just the index of the specific row instead of returning the list of all the indices

Comment: I am not sure if understand. If use `df = pd.DataFrame({'xk':[0,2,0],
                   'yk':[0,5,0],
                   'aa':[0,1,0]})

print (df)` and then you get DataFrame -  `a = (df.ix[(df['xk']  == 0) & (df['yk'] == 0)])`. Do you need return e.g. first index or second index value by position?